# Can I create a keyword subdirectory for my home page to help SEO?

Tags: google-search, htaccess, url, 301-redirect, keywords

My website consists of an English-language Homepage (my `index.html` file), and a German and Russian translation of this page (`de.html` + `ru.html`), which are accessible through a button on the top-right.

After some research regarding SEO, I discovered that placing a keyword into the URL itself is helpful for search result visibility. I now wonder how I can accomplish that.

Should I create a new subdirectory in my public root and give it a keyword as its name? Then place the `index.html` file (and the two translations – `de.html` + `ru.html`) into this folder, so that my URL is always `www.example.com/keyword/***.html` in the search results? I suspect this requires some redirecting and *.htaccess( change, but I’m not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create a keyword subdirectory for my home page to help SEO?

You could, however, this may not help much with SEO. The URL doesn't necessarily help that much with *ranking* (on page content is what really matters), although it could perhaps help click through rates when users see the URL/keyword in search results.

> I suspect this requires some redirecting...

However, if you are *changing* an established URL structure then this may even have a negative SEO effect - at least initially. *Changing* the URL structure always carries a certain amount of risk.

But yes, if you are *changing* the URL structure then you will need to implement an external redirect in order to *preserve* SEO. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/index.html" to "/keyword/index.html"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /keyword/index\.html [R=301,L]
```

(It's not clear from your question whether `index.html` is actually part of the visible URL, or you are simply letting mod_dir serve the DirectoryIndex document having requested the *directory*.)

> ...and a German and Russian translation of this page

But don't you also need the corresponding German and Russian keywords in the URL, not the same (presumably) English keyword?

> Should I create a new subdirectory in my public root and give it a keyword as its name?

You could, but you don't necessarily need to create a physical subdirectory by that name - it could be entirely *virtual*, and use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` to internally rewrite the request to the appropriate file. (An *internal rewrite* is entirely internal to the server and hidden from users - the visible URL in the browser's address bar does not change.) However, having the different translations entirely separate in their own subdirectory could be advantageous since you will often have different images and stylesheets that accompany different translations.

For example, to *internally rewrite* the requested URL from `/keyword/index.html` to `/index.html` (the actual file) then you could do something like the following *after* the external redirect (above):

```
# Rewrite "/keyword/index.html" to "/index.html"
RewriteRule ^keyword/index\.html$ /index.html [L]
```

> English-language Homepage (my `index.html` file), and a German and Russian translation of this page (`de.html` + `ru.html`)

For consistency, I would also consider having `en.html` (or similar) instead of `index.html` for your English language version.

You could then have home page URLs of the form `/en/`, `/de/` and `/ru/` - which is more obvious to users.